# Can Smart Storage Battery disable access to server?

Tags: storage, hp-proliant, remote-access, hpe, battery

I have a Proliant DL360 Gen9 server that I have to restart every 5-7 days because I loose access to VMware and to all virtual machines. By this, I mean that I cannot SSH to the virtual machines or even ping the server, same happens with the web access or ping to the VMware interface. Even by logging into the iLO interfaces I cannot open the console to VMware, so each time this happens I have no option rather than to reboot the server to regain access to the virtual machines and the VMware service.

While trying to find out what was the cause of it, the only thing I can see is that the Smart Storage Battery status is degraded. Next you can see the images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am no expert in servers so I would like to know if this could be the cause of the server not responding. While reading the [oficial documentation](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-a00026525en_us) I can see that the possible consequenses of having this issue are: "error messages may be in the server IML logs and OS system logs", "controller cache is disabled" and "server performance is reduced", but there is nothing about loosing access to it. Could problems with Smart Storage Battery actually be the cause of this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

PS: Next is the system information if it can help for anything:

[image]

Comment: It's doubtful that's the cause of the issue, but why don't you replace the faulty component and find out?

Comment: if it is the cause we would replace it immediatelly, otherwise we would not treat it as urgently.